# change inner backslashed quotes

Tags: cursor-movement, cursor-motions, map-operator, custom-text-object

I know the `ci"` motion and others `:change`s, but I need something like a `ci\"` in order to change inner a backslashed quotes. Assuming `*` as the cursor position:

```
a = "message says: \"fo*o bar\""
```

I would like to perform a `ci` which gives me a:

```
a = "message says: \"*\""
```

And then start writing inside the backslashed quotes.

Answer (score 2):

This could be implemented using:
https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user

Lots of existing plugins are close to this behavior, but none seems to answer the question yet.